# Mathematical operations on MySQL DECIMAL data type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, math, decimal, sqldatatypes

I am storing money values on a MySQL table and I'm using DECIMAL as the data type. I need to grab these elements, do some basic mathematical operations on these values (addition, subtraction, sums, etc.), display the results to the user, and place them in a separate table. I know that MySQL allows you to do addition and sums within a table, but is there any way to do it as a PHP variable? I know in PHP you can use intval() to convert a string number to an integer, but that loses the decimal values in the conversion. Something similar would work for me because I can always convert it back to a string and enter it back in a different MySQL table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has [(int)](http://php.net/int) for integer and [(float)](http://php.net/float) for your problem.

PHP can do mathematical operations (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`%`) without defining the type and without any problems

```
$var1 = 1.56;
$var2 = 0.34;
$sum = $var1+$var2; // 1.90
```

Comment: So PHP can do a mathematical operation even if the variable is a string? The output data from MySQL will be in the form of $var1 = "20.54" not $var1 = 20.54. If I understand you correctly, PHP will treat both equally even though if is_numeric($var1) = false.

Comment: Why don't you make a test enviorment just to see :)

Comment: PHP doesn't really care what the variable type is, it'll multiply it anyway, much like Perl. PHP is about as weakly typed as you can get.

Comment: I actually tested it using the SUM() function on the array of columns from the MySQL table, but got an error because it was a string. I had to use $sum = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cc_amnt) AS cc_sum FROM " .$tablename)) in order to get an actual sum of the columns.

Comment: I guess I'm used to coding in C++ where variable declaration is very important. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get the variables out of MySQL, and then you can perform simple arithmatic as per this manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

For instance

```
$a = '0.002';
$b = '1.1';

echo $c = $a + $b; // Outputs 1.1002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a float with 
    floatval($stringVar)

PHP's supports mathematical operators.

So if you have $a and $b.

```
$a + $b; 
$a - $b; 
$a * $b; 
$a / $b; 
$a % $b;
```